# Ignite data backup in hard disk

Tags: ignite, persistent-storage

So i'm totally new to ignite here. Is there any configuration or strategy to export all data present in the cache memory to the local hard disk in ignite.

Basically what i'm hoping for is some kind of a logger/snapshot that shows the change in data when any kind of sql update operation is performed on the data present in the caches.

If someone could sugest a solution, i'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and configure persistence store for any cache [1]. If cluster is restarted, all the data will be there and can be reloaded into memory using `IgniteCache#loadCache(..)` method. Out of the box Ignite provides integration with RDBMS [2] and Cassandra [3].

Additionally, in one of the future versions (most likely next 2.1) Ignite will provide a local disk persistence storage which will allow to run with a cold cache, i.e. without explicit reloading after cluster restart. I would recommend to monitor dev and user Apache Ignite mailing lists for more details.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

[2] https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/automatic-rdbms-integration

[3] https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra